# Why is the last chained ".then" being evaluated before the function chained before it?

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise

I have a simple `$q` system set up in Angular.

The controller consists of just:

```
     var fun1 = function(){
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        $timeout(function(){
            console.log("fun1 resolving...");
            deferred.resolve(5);
        }, 1000);


        return deferred.promise;
    }
    var fun2 = function(){
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        $timeout(function(){
            console.log("fun2 resolving...");
            deferred.resolve(6);
        }, 1000);

        return deferred.promise;
    }
    var promise = fun1().then(fun2()).then(function(data){
        console.log(data);
    });
```

I'm expecting it to print out:

```
fun1 resolving....
fun2 resolving....
5
```

But instead it prints out

```
fun1 resolving....
5
fun2 resolving....
```

This seems strange to me. Why is the `console.log` of the last chained `.then()` evaluating before actual `fun2()` itself?

Answer (score 2):

Isn't that because you are calling `fun2`, instead of just passing it in the `then`?

Just like:

```
var promise = fun1().then(fun2).then(function(data){
    console.log(data);
});
```

But then the result wil be:

```
fun1 resolving....
fun2 resolving....
6
```

Instead of outputting 5, because `fun2` will pass 6 (`deferred.resolve(6);`) to your last callback.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be a difference between your code and my code?

Comment: Sorry, i mistyped. fun2 should be passed, not called.

Comment: I cannot comment on the other answer (not enough reputation yet). But what happens is that Javascript first evaluates your expressions, hence when you pass fun2() to the promise chain, it is evaluated right away. What is executed after fun1 ends, is the result of executing fun2(), which in your example does nothing meaningful.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are executing `fun2()` instead of providing `fun2` as a function:

```
var promise = fun1().then(fun2).then(function(data){
    console.log(data);
});
```

`then` expects a function that returns a promise.

Comment: I don't understand... then shouldn't it execute before the last `then()` since it is connected earlier?

Comment: Since it is not fulfilling the promise chain, then the promise chain does not wait until `fun2` is done.

Comment: @Imray it happens for coincidence, because both have the same timeout. raise `fun1` timeout and you see the difference.

Comment: So by typing `fun2()`, it gets executed right way, even though it's packaged inside the `then()`? weird no?

Comment: The promise chain fulfillment (to `console.log(data);`) is just queued ahead of your `fun2` timeout.  Once `fun1` is finished there is no async in the chain because `fun2` is called with `fun2()`.  So, it just keeps going.